# Should this question be bifurcated : Une règle pour l'usage de « à » vs « de » ?

Tags: discussion

Though the OP might not have known *a priori*, *a posteriori* [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/279/1995) concerns 2 different syntaxes, as proven by [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/285/1995)'s bifurcation.

Answer (score 3):

La réponse a reçu réponse, si j'ai bien compris, cette requête porte sur le fait de transformer la question posée en 2 questions au lieu d'une seule?

Je n'ai pas bien compris l'intérêt, car la question originale porte sur le fait de choisir "à" plutôt que "de" ou l'inverse.

La question devrait être un peu plus explicite. Il faudrait par exemple coller les éléments qui permettent de comprendre la question posée ici, en faisant des citations.